# SignaturePad: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Tags: angular, signaturepad

I'm currenly working on an angular workspace that has already been made some time ago, but that hasn't been modified or updated since years. Now that I have to work on it, there is one project which I'm not able to build, giving me the title error after the build command. I've tried everything I could think of: rerun npm install, reinstall node, reinstall angular, but nothing. I think it may be like this because the SignaturePad library I'm using (angular2-signature) looks like it's not supported anymore, but even if that was the problem the software should work anyway, right?

app.module.ts:

```
import { Helper } from './shared/helper';
import { FaceDetectionService } from './services/face-detection-service';
import { DossierService } from './services/dossier.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ExpertComponent } from './components/expert/expert.component';
import { ClientComponent } from './components/client/client.component';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { FirebaseService } from './services/firebase.service';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule, FirestoreSettingsToken } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad'
import { VideoPeriziaComponent } from './components/video-perizia/video-perizia.component';
import { ExpertInfoComponent } from './components/expert-info/expert-info.component';
import { ImageService } from './services/image.service';
import { PriceAgreementComponent } from './components/price-agreement/price-agreement.component';
import { MatDialogModule, MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { ReportService } from './services/report.service';
import { NgxAgoraModule } from 'ngx-agora';
import { environment } from '../../src/environments/environment';
import { SdUiLibraryModule } from 'projects/sd-ui-library/src/public-api';
import { AllowShootingDialogComponent } from './components/allow-shooting-dialog/allow-shooting-dialog.component';
import { AGORA_CONFIG } from './shared/constants';
import { ElementaryBranchesCardComponent } from './components/elementary-branches-card/elementary-branches-card.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ExpertComponent,
    ClientComponent,
    VideoPeriziaComponent,
    ExpertInfoComponent,
    PriceAgreementComponent,
    AllowShootingDialogComponent,
    ElementaryBranchesCardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    ToastrModule.forRoot({timeOut: 3000, positionClass: 'toast-top-left'}),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    NgxAgoraModule.forRoot(AGORA_CONFIG),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    SignaturePad,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FontAwesomeModule,
    SdUiLibraryModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatInputModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    DossierService,
    FirebaseService,
    FaceDetectionService,
    ImageService,
    ReportService,
    Helper,
    { provide: FirestoreSettingsToken, useValue: {} }
],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

signaturepad.component

```
import { AfterContentInit, ElementRef, EventEmitter, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import * as ɵngcc0 from '@angular/core';
export interface Point {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    time: number;
}
export declare type PointGroup = Array<Point>;
export declare class SignaturePad implements AfterContentInit, OnDestroy {
    options: any;
    onBeginEvent: EventEmitter<boolean>;
    onEndEvent: EventEmitter<boolean>;
    private signaturePad;
    private elementRef;
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef);
    ngAfterContentInit(): void;
    ngOnDestroy(): void;
    resizeCanvas(): void;
    toData(): Array<PointGroup>;
    fromData(points: Array<PointGroup>): void;
    toDataURL(imageType?: string, quality?: number): string;
    fromDataURL(dataURL: string, options?: any): void;
    clear(): void;
    isEmpty(): boolean;
    off(): void;
    on(): void;
    set(option: string, value: any): void;
    onBegin(): void;
    onEnd(): void;
    queryPad(): any;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<SignaturePad, never>;
    static ɵcmp: ɵngcc0.ɵɵComponentDefWithMeta<SignaturePad, "signature-pad", never, { "options": "options"; }, { "onBeginEvent": "onBeginEvent"; "onEndEvent": "onEndEvent"; }, never, never>;
}
```

Comment: Did you try importing `SignaturePadModule` instead?

Comment: @OctavianMărculescu sadly yes, and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

That was mentioned in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/wulfsolter/angular2-signaturepad/issues/105

Remove the word "Module" from your import from this:

`import { SignaturePadModule } from 'angular2-signaturepad';`

to:

`import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad';`